# Django - Cannot pass id of Django form to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I read the django documentation and a django form field id should have the format id_(form field name), but when I try to reference this id when assigning the form field to a javascript variable it returns null. To test this, I used auto_id to make sure the id I used in javascript matches the field id I am trying to reference and it does. Additionally, I passed another html element ("testid") to my javascript to make sure it works with the rest of the elements in the template and it does. Why would I be able to assign the id of all of my html elements to a javascript variable but not the django form?

forms.py (list of choices not included to save space)

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    dataset = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Select(choices=DATASET_CHOICES))
    graph_type = forms.CharField(label='',  widget=forms.Select(choices=GRAPH_CHOICES))
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load materializecss %}
{% block content %}
    <form action = "", method = "POST">
        {{form|materializecss}}
    </form>
        {{form.graph_type.auto_id}}
    <div id = "testid"></div> 
{% endblock %}
```

main.js

```
const carInput = document.getElementById("id_graph_type")
const testInput = document.getElementById("testid")

carInput.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    console.log('Changed')
})
testInput.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    console.log('Changed')
})
```

here is the html output for the form to the browser

```
<form action = "", method = "POST">
    <div class="input-field col s12  ">
                <select name="dataset" 
        class=" validate">
                          <option value="Choose a Dataset">Choose a Dataset</option>
                          <option value="US Mortality By State">US Mortality By State</option>
                          <option value="US Average temperature">US Average temperature</option>
                          <option value="Food Prices By State">Food Prices By State</option>      
                </select>
                <label class="control-label s12 "></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12  ">

                <select name="graph_type" 
        class=" validate" 
 >
                          <option value="Choose Plot Type">Choose Plot Type</option>
                          <option value="Bar Graph">Bar Graph</option>
                          <option value="Line Graph">Line Graph</option>
                          <option value="Count Plot">Count Plot</option>
                </select>
                <label class="control-label s12 "></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaterializeCSS doesn't appear to set an `id` attribute on the form fields in the rendered html by default.

You should be able to do it manually (but this is really a materializecss limitation, not a Django issue).

Set the `id` in your widget:

```
graph_type = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Select(choices=GRAPH_CHOICES, attrs={'id': 'id_graph_type'}))
```

That should work to get the materializecss template tag to render the id into your HTML.